# How do we handle long text in mobile screens in card view of fixed width?

Tags: html, css, user-experience, typography

Would like to know any user friendly way to show text with huge length for a card of fixed width and height(as we have multiple cards for symmetry height and width are fixed for a card). In web view we are providing hover feature, so on hover complete text will appear. We just need a quick solution for mobile view just for now.
One solution is allowing user to scroll text. Any other better approach ?

Answer (score 1):

`text-overflow: ellipsis;` is a reasonably common pattern (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).
And would be a quick solution.

However, I don't think it's the best from a UX perspective unless you provide the means for the user to see the whole piece of text (similar to what Guy has said in their answer).

A combination of `ellipsis` and a press to scroll/reveal would probably be slightly better.

In an ideal world you define content boundaries and design for that. For example, a title should have minimum 2 and maximum 100 characters, then you can design your title block for worst case scenario and give it a height that supports 100 characters without needing ellipsis at all.

This is called different things in different businesses, but usually falls under the broader umbrella of a [content strategy](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/content-marketing-plan)

Comment: A combination of ellipsis and a press to scroll/reveal would probably be slightly better -- This is my current thought. Will check further on other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your design looks like, but you can try using `overflow:hidden` and fade out the text at the end of your card, when a user will click on the card it will open in full view (or any other way).

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you had added an image of your design, but you can try,
(1): decreasing the size of your design (all the cards) proportionally and make it so if the user clicks on the card it expands and adds the text.
(2): in mobile view change the design to x rows and 2 columns, so you get to retain the length and width of the card.